# How to print PCAPNG metadata in Python?

Tags: python, wireshark, pcap, libpcap, pcap-ng

I'm attempting my first Python program and could use a little help.
[My script on github](https://github.com/jonschipp/metacapng-test/blob/master/metacapng.py)

I need a way to print the metadata in a PCAPNG file. I want to print the
application and version, OS, and interface for starters. The Section Header Block and the
Interface Description Block contain the data I need.

My problem is the blocks/fields are not at a fixed size because of the Options field in each block: 
[PCAPNG format](https://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html), See section 3.1 and 3.2

**Questions:**

1.) Are there any Python libraries that print that information? 
2.) If not, are there any ways through Python that information could be easily grabbed

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try https://pypi.org/project/pcapng/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such libraries, you will have to write your own parser for the PCAPNG Section Header Blocks.

Another option is to implement code to do a HTTP POST of the PCAPNG file to [pcapng.com](http://pcapng.com) and parse the extracted metadata from the HTML result.